# Scatter an array in cyclic distribution

Tags: mpi

I have a problem of data distribution using MPI functions.

I have an array `A` in the memory of the process of rank 0, and I want to distribute it (using a function like `MPI_Scatter`) to all the processes, except that I want it in *cyclic distribution* in the end. Assuming that there are `p`, then the process of rank `i` should get `A[i], A[i+p], A[i+2p], ...`.

I tried to combine `MPI_Scatter` with the use of a custom data type that has a stride, e.g.

```
MPI_Datatype cyclic;
MPI_Type_vector(1, 1, p, MPI_DOUBLE, &cyclic);
MPI_Type_commit(&cyclic);

MPI_Scatter(X, n/p, cyclic, Y, n/p, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The end result is as if I had not a normal `MPI_Scatter`.

I also tried `MPI_Scatterv` with `displs[i] == i`, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

The custom type needed to be resized...

```
MPI_Datatype strided, cyclic;
MPI_Aint extent, lb;
MPI_Type_vector(n/p, 1, p, MPI_DOUBLE, &strided);
MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_DOUBLE, &lb, &extent);
MPI_Type_create_resized(strided, 0, extent, &cyclic);
MPI_Type_commit(&cyclic);
MPI_Scatter(X,1,cyclic, Y,n/p,MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```